# How are questions migrated?

Tags: discussion

Apologies if I should know this, but if a question fairly obviously belongs on another site, what do I do? Flag for Mod attention?

Comment: Good question, it's frustrating that only History Meta appears under migration. I remember reading somewhere that we can't migrate because we're beta (yes, beta again!). I think we have to flag it - hopefully a mod will clear this up.

Answer (score 5):

Beta sites are not given direct migration paths as a matter of network policy. The only thing we can do is to rely on case by case moderator action. As such, please vote to close with a custom reason to migrate to whichever stack it should be on, and flag for moderator attention. We'll ask the target stack if they want it, and transfer it if possible.

The reason for using a custom reason is because if people voted to close with the default meta one, it just punts the question here.

Even after we graduate, we won't have default migration paths to every other stack. If the question belongs on an unlisted stack, custom close and flagging for moderator action will continue to be the way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the "this belongs on another stack" option and, as you say, was only offered Meta! I'll flag it next time - frustrating, though!

Comment: @TheHonRose - One of the "fun" things I look forward to upon site graduation will be compiling our list of default migration paths. I already know three I'd put on there for sure, a fourth I'd argue for, and a fifth I'd argue against.